# can i know if QNetworkAccessManager done processing all http requests?

Tags: c++, qt, http, signals

im using  QNetworkAccessManager in each httpClient object creation in my app and delete it after the HttpClass go out of stack, I have something like 300 http requests
im doing in aloop , I know that from 4.8 the http requests are Multithreading  so I have no fear to execute as meany as I like , and its working great .
the problem is say how can I know when all the thread requests are done (all the 300 ) can I emit some signal ?
this is the loop of the request , in side the http client there are the usual http signals

```
    QMapIterator<QString,QString> i(m_urlMap);

    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        i.next();        
        QString sUrl = i.value();;
         HttpClient* pHttpClient = new  HttpClient(m_pFileOutput,m_pMutex);
         bool bReturnInvokeHttpClient = false;
         bReturnInvokeHttpClient = pHttpClient->startRequest(sUrl);


    }
```

do I need manully keep track on each httpclient m when it done its job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QNetworkAccessManager has only a signal which goes off when **a** request finishes, but there isn't one that goes off when the last one does. So I'm afraif you'll have to keep track yourself.

Best regards